# fluxgui won't allow me to enter zip code information

Tags: arch-linux

I ran `yay -S fluxgui` and successfully installed version 1.1.10-1 of the package. But when I run `fluxgui` from the command line, two windows pop up, one with this message:

```
The f.lux indicator applet needs to know your latitude or zipcode to run. Please fill either of them in on the preferences screen and click 'Close'.
```

When I click "OK," that window and the other one, the preferences window in which I must enter my zip code information, disappear.

Here's the output in the terminal afterward.

```
Error: Please install xflux in the PATH 

Critical error. Exiting.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/fluxgui", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fluxgui/fluxapp.py", line 213, in main
    app = FluxGUI()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fluxgui/fluxapp.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.exit(1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fluxgui/fluxapp.py", line 46, in exit
    gtk.main_quit()
RuntimeError: called outside of a mainloop
```

How do I set my zip code in `fluxgui` on Arch?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're the one that posted on the [AUR page for fluxgui](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/fluxgui#comment-696574), but it looks like that is a bug with the package itself.

The [README for fluxgui](https://github.com/xflux-gui/fluxgui#flux-indicator-applet) mentions that it is only a GUI; it doesn't actually provide the flux program itself,

> This project -- https://github.com/xflux-gui/fluxgui -- is only concerned with the fluxgui indicator applet program, not with the underlying xflux program the indicator applet controls.

I'd ensure that 1) [flux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xflux) is actually installed, and 2) all of the [Python dependencies for the fluxgui](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/fluxgui/#comment-686282) are installed correctly.

Comment: I have `xflux` installed but when I run `yay -S fluxgui` I get this message: `fluxgui and xflux are in conflict. Remove xflux?`

Comment: They shouldn't conflict; I believe that to be an error with the PKGBUILD, (See: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1850670#p1850670).